# Can't create custom MapType: google.maps.MapType is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create my own MapType, but it causes

```
Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.MapType is not a function
```

And It's weird, because API is actually loaded - all other functions works well if I comment/delete MapType code:

```
var customMapType = new google.maps.MapType({
    maxZoom: 24
});
```

Here's map initialization:

```
function initMap(placeholderId, aCenter)
{
    var mapOptions =
            {
                center: aCenter,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                scaleControl: true,
                rotateControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            }

    return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(placeholderId), mapOptions);
}
```

API initialization:

```
function InitializeLayoutControl(onLoadComplete, googleAPIKey)
{
    loadCompleteCallback = onLoadComplete;
    loadScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v3.exp&" + ((typeof googleAPIKey === 'undefined' || googleAPIKey === '') ? "" : "key=" + googleAPIKey + "&") + "callback=LoadComplete&libraries=drawing,places,geometry");
}
```

(this works well)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  How are you loading the API? Are you trying to create the `customMapType` before the Google Maps Javascript API v3 has loaded?

Comment: Added API initialization code. No, I'm trying to do this AFTER API loading.

Comment: The API is being loaded asynchronously, the code that uses it (like your `customMapType` definition) needs to be inside the initialize function, which runs after it is loaded.  I don't see it there.  Second request, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: My first try was inside initialization function - same error

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change from `google.maps.MapType` to `google.maps.ImageMapType`

according to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en

Haven't had a chance to try it but it looks like the problem.

Comment: From same page: "Additionally, the ImageMapType class provides some built-in behavior to simplify the creation of imagery MapTypes."

Answer (score 0):

The google.maps.MapType is an interface. Please take a look at this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapType). This cannot be used directly you must access it through the classes that implements it or create a class to implement it. You need  may need a [MapTypeRegistry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en#MapTypeRegistry) in creating a custom Map Type. This stores the custom map types for that particular map.

This is the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en#MapTypeRegistry) on the documentation:

```
// Modify the control to only display two maptypes, the
// default ROADMAP and the custom 'mymap'.
// Note that because this is simply an association, we
// don't need to modify the MapTypeRegistry beforehand.

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'mymaps';

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
center: brooklyn,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
  mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
},
  mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
};

// Create our map. This creation will implicitly create a
// map type registry.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    mapOptions);

// Create your custom map type using your own code.
// (See below.)
var myMapType = new MyMapType();

// Set the registry to associate 'mymap' with the
// custom map type we created, and set the map to
// show that map type.
map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, myMapType);
```